# jQuery select all rows from the first table out of three identical ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm scraping data using the `cheerio` library which allows me to use `jQuery` selectors inside my `node.JS` application.
The website I'm scraping data from contains three tables, all of these tables have same class names and are identical.
The amount of table rows (`tr`) inside these tables may vary.

Underneath is a HTML skeleton of one of the tables:

```
<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 1</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 2</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 3</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 4</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I'd like to do is select all the rows from the first table **only** and eventually output those texts as `JSON`. How would I achieve this when all those tables are basically identical (identical class names)?

Underneath is what I've tried so far but it still outputs the text from all the three tables instead of just the first.

```
var that = $(this);
that.first('table.component').find("tr.body-row").each(function(){
    console.log(that.find('span.data').text());
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `that` exactly?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's a variable referring `$(this)`. I've declared it in my code but forgot to include it in here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAKE USE OF `.first()` jquery function to get the first table and then use `$(this)` inside the `.each` function instead of `that`

```js
$(function(){
  $(".component").first().find('.body-row').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('span.data').text());
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 1</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 2</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 3</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 4</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 1</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 2</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 3</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 4</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 1</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 2</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 3</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 4</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, the expected output is just as I wanted it to be. Cheers, mate! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

select the first table

```
$('table.component').first()
```

```js
$('table.component').first().find("tr.body-row td span span.data").each(function(index,elem){
    console.log(elem.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 1</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 2</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 3</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 4</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table class="component">
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 7</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 8</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to scrape these values -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="body-row">
        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 9</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>    

        <td class="column">
            <span class="display-inline-block">
                <span class="data">Text 10</span> <!-- I'd like to be able to output these values as JSON -->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```